# How to make it by list comprehension

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to get the child list under the parent list as a group.

```py
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cleaning_type = serializers.CharField(source='cleaning_type.cleaning_type_name')
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'cleaning_type','service_name')


class ServiceTypeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    queryset = Service.objects.all()
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the service types.
        """
        servicename_list = Service.objects.all()
        return servicename_list
```

It shows:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Floors",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Bathrooms",
            
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "cleaning_type": "Lite service",
            "service_name": "Kitchen",
            
        }
    ]
```

**I want this to be in the following format:**

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    cleaning_type: 'Lite service',
    service_name: ['Floors', 'bathroom', 'kitchen'],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cleaning_type: 'Moving cleaning',
    service_name: ['Kitchen Including All Appliances And Cabinets'],
  },
]
```

That means all child elements will be under a separate parent list. Not separate by separate.

**models.py** is here:

**Cleaning Type Model:**

```
class CleaningType(models.Model):
    cleaning_type_name = models.CharField(
        _("Select Cleaning Type"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

    price = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cleaning_type_name
```

**Service  Model:**

```
class Service(models.Model):

   cleaning_type = models.ForeignKey(
        CleaningType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   service_name = models.CharField(
       _("Service Name"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

  

#string type added
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.service_name)
```

I want sub categories under parent caterories. Here cleaning_type is the parent category and service is the child category of cleaning_type. i.e : cleaning_type >> service_type

Comment: Do you want to combine several service objects?

Comment: @DavidLu  Yes. I want to combine several service objects.

Comment: But I don't know about how they can be combined? How they are considered as the same group?

Comment: @DavidLu If you think those subcategories then i want sub categories under parent caterories. Here cleaning_type is the parent category and service_type is the child category of cleaning_type. i.e : cleaning_type >> service_type

Comment: Then I think the database design is not good.

Comment: Can you add the `ServiceType` and `CleaningType` model into this post?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to move the `cleaningtype` field into the `ServiceType` model.
And I think it's better to set the `related_name` from the view of the target model.

```
class ServiceType(models.Model):
    cleaningtype = models.ForeignKey(
        CleaningType, related_name='service_types', on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
    ...

class Service(models.Model):        
    servicetype = models.ForeignKey(
        ServiceType, related_name='services', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_name = models.CharField(
        _("Service Name"), blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    
    #string type added
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.service_name)
```

And in `CleaningTypeSerializer`

```
class CleaningTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service_objects = ServiceTypeSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
    service_types = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        Model = CleaningType
        fields = ('id', 'cleaning_type', 'service_types',)
   
    def get_service_types(self, obj):
        return list(obj.service_types.values_list('service_type').distinct())
```

Finally in views.py,

```
class CleaningTypesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CleaningTypeSerializer
    queryset = CleaningType.objects.all()
```

You can get the list of `CleaningType` data from this `CleaningTypesViewSet`.

Comment: Could you show the error?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWEZc.png

Comment: Where did you define `service_types` field ?